# Linux command services universal

Tags: linux, service, command, universal

Exist any command to start, stop and show status service for all linux distribution?
This command suporte all services, example yajsw.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, but you can address a group of distributions that adhere to `SysVinit` or `systemd`.

Here's a quick side-by-side list of common service commands: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SysVinit_to_Systemd_Cheatsheet

Comment: I use command "service" in ubuntu and sucess!
Use command "systemctl" in two diferent versions of opensuse and 1 sucess, the version 13.2 sucess and the version 9.3 failure. What is the diference?

Comment: I cannot seem to find the link where it was mentioned, but in earlier version of `systemd` you have to specify the full service name, with `.service` appended. Ex: `systemctl start ntpd.service`. Does this resolve your issue?